# Javascript - Pegar id do objeto em uma lista gerada com PHP e HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como pego o id do objeto de uma lista enviando como parâmetro para uma função javascript. Como coloco o id na função enviar()?

```html
<?php foreach ($contatos as $contato) {
        ?>
        <!-- Inicio da tabela (Na verdade é uma div com nome tabela)-->
        <div class="tabela">
            <!-- Todo conteúdo da tabela -->
            <div class="conteudo">
                <!-- Parte somente texto -->
                <div class="textos">
                    <!--Mostrando nome do contato -->
                    <span class="nome"><?php
                        if (!empty($contato->getNome())) {
                            echo $contato->getNome();
                        } else {
                            echo "Nome não cadastrado.";
                        }
                        ?></span><br>
                    <br>
                    <!-- Imagem do telefone -->
                    <img src="../imagens/fone.png" width="16px" height="16px"> 
                    <!-- Mostrando telefone-->
                    <?php
                    if (!empty($contato->getFone())) {
                        echo $contato->getFone();
                    } else {
                        echo "Telefone não cadastrado.";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <br>
                </div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                
                <!-- Botão enviar-->
                <!-- Se contato ja foi transmitido não mostre a opção de enviar-->
                <!-- Se não foi transmitido, mostre a opção de enviar-->
                <?php if ($contato->getTransmitido() == 0) { ?>
                    <div class="botaoenviar" >    
                        <a href="#" class="button" name="enviar" onclick="enviar();" ><img src="../imagens/enviar.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

            </div>
            <!-- Traço finalizador da tabela -->
            <div class="traco"></div>


        </div>



        <?php
    }?>
```

Comment: `onclick="enviar(<?php echo $contato->getId(); ?>);"` ? Qual *id* você se refere, do registro do banco, certo? Como faz para pega-lo? `$contato->getId()` ou algo assim ? Precisa especificar mais...

Comment: Deu certo é isso mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu objeto deve ter um método do tipo `getID()`. Então pode fazer assim:

```
<a href="#" class="button" name="enviar" onclick="enviar(<?php echo $contato->getID(); ?>);" ><img src="../imagens/enviar.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de como eu faria com jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="botao" id="botao1" cor="red">Botão A</button>
<button class="botao" id="botao2" cor="blue">Botão B</button>
<button class="botao" id="botao3" cor="green">Botão C</button>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".botao").click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr("cor"));
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    });
</script>
```